# Markup Extensions in WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, markup-extensions

Has anyone ever created a custom markup extension in WPF or Silverlight?  When would you ever want or need to do this?  Any tips or sources on how to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about WPF or Silverlight, it's hell of a lot different, especially in this aspect...

Answer (score 9):

An example would be for [Localization](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html):

> A simple and effective way to localize application resources is to
>   write a custom MarkupExtension that *provides a localized value*. The
>   extension takes a parameter that is a unique
>   resource key... [and then] looks up the value from a generic resource provider.

Note: You can not write custom markup extensions in silverlight.

Comment: Ah, another in it's many limitations.  I can't wait for Mix so I can figure out if they fixed this shit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is handy and I have created one myself. I created a markup extension called *EvalBinding* that takes a set of bindings as children and a C# evaluation string. It evaluates the C# to process the values from the child bindings so that I do not need to create many simple *TypeConverter* classes.

For example I can do this...

```
<EvalBinding Eval="(this[0] > this[1] ? 'GT' : 'LTE')">
    <Binding ElementName="element1" Path="Size"/>
    <Binding ElementName="element2" Path="Size"/>
<EvalBinding>
```

Where *this* is a reference to the array of child binding results.

For resources on implementing a MarkupExtension...

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx)

[Josh Smith Blog Entry](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/05/25/a-review-of-markup-extensions/)

[Rob Relyea Blog Entry](http://www.windows-now.com/blogs/rrelyea/archive/2006/02/03/MarkupExtensionAsAnObjectElement.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Hooray!!

This is implemented in Silverlight 5!!

And furthermore, now it's a generic interface instead of a class!!

[Check it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712747%28VS.96%29.aspx).

Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2011/04/28/markup-extensions-in-silverlight-5.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Unfortunately the links are dead and I can't understand what this answer means without them.

Answer (score 0):

I use a markup extension to standardise my validation bindings. So the benefit here is small, 4 of the defaults I don't have to set anymore, and if I wish to change them in the future, I do it here only.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace ITIS 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a normal Binding but defaults NotifyOnValidationError to True,
    /// ValidatesOnExceptions to True, Mode to TwoWay and 
    /// UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class ValidatedBinding : MarkupExtension
    {
        public ValidatedBinding(string path)
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

            UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;

            Path = path;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new Binding(Path) {
                Converter = this.Converter,
                ConverterParameter = this.ConverterParameter,
                ElementName = this.ElementName,
                FallbackValue = this.FallbackValue,
                Mode = this.Mode,
                NotifyOnValidationError = true,
                StringFormat = this.StringFormat,
                ValidatesOnExceptions = true,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = this.UpdateSourceTrigger
            };
        }

        public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

        public object ConverterParameter { get; set; }

        public string ElementName { get; set; }

        public object FallbackValue { get; set; }

        public BindingMode Mode { get; set; }

        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string StringFormat { get; set; }

        public UpdateSourceTrigger UpdateSourceTrigger { get; set; }
    }
}
```